# Self Refrential Stacks

Tags: c, stack, typedef

Suppose we have a stack as defined below:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

I copied this definition from a book but I'm not exactly sure what the last 2 lines do. Does the node declaration at the end have anything to do with the structure declaration or is it just an object that we are creating?

Comment: Did the book not explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering last two line:

1:

```
struct node *next;
```

explains: you are creating a pointer variable (i.e, next) of type struct node and capable of holding address of the same type. usually the concept comes when you want implement the stack operation dynamically.

```
+--+----+    +--+----+    +--+----+    +--+----+
|10|2000|    |20|3000|    |30|4000|    |40|NULL|
+--+----+    +--+----+    +--+----+    +--+----+
  1000         2000         3000         4000
```

it can be seen that the next part is handling the address of the another structure and hence you need the pointer of type struct node.

2:

```
typedef struct {
type1 fieldname1;
type2 fieldname2;
....
typeN fieldnameN;
} NEW_TYPE;

NEW_TYPE variable_identifier;
```

Here the `NEW_TYPE` is the typedef name can be used like any type.

I have tried giving the generic syntax. hope you get it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is equivalent to:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
```

By separating `typedef` with the `struct node` type, it's easier to see `node` in your code is an alias for `struct node` made by `typedef`.